# Is it possible to buy a computer monitor and HRM watch in Colombo, Sri Lanka duty-free airport shops?

Tags: electronic-items, duty-free, sri-lanka, colombo

I'd like to take a monitor with me as a checked baggage, but it is an international flight with one change so it seems quite risky. So I would like to buy one at Colombo Airport duty-free shop. Do they sell monitors there? Would it be cheaper than buying it somewhere in Sri Lanka after arrival?

Also I'd like to buy some HRM watch, either Polar, or Garmin, or FitBit, or smth. Do they sell such things in airport duty-free shops?

Comment: One question is whether you'll actually be able to access the duty free shop. won't you be funneled to immigration, then customs/luggage, and then out? That is, no opportunity to access the shops.

Answer (score 2):

The web site for the Colombo airport has a [list of shops](http://www.airport.lk/passenger-guide/shopping-dining.php) in the airport. Although I'm a bit puzzled as to how one would buy a washing machine in a duty-free shop, and carry it on the plane, it clearly states that there are multiple duty-free shops selling such home appliances, and TVs.  So you may be able to find a monitor (or a TV that would work as a monitor).

Check the same list to see if any stores are likely to sell the other items you're looking for as well.

Whether it's cheaper to buy a monitor (or any other item) in a duty-free shop versus anywhere else is an immensely complicated question which we cannot begin to answer, since it would literally require checking the prices of items in every retail outlet.  But you can see [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/14015/444) for some discussion of the relevant topics.

Comment: I assume they purchase it and then have it delivered; but yes - it boggles the mind.

Comment: You would buy the appliances after landing and take them home in a taxi.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: I suppose, but that violates the spirit, if not the law, of "duty free" in most jurisdictions (where the assumption is that the purchaser will export the purchased goods, therefore making them exempt from local taxes). Likely such laws don't exist, or simply aren't enforced, in a place where they sell appliances in a "duty free" store--or the term "duty free" may simply not be regulated like it is in some markets.

Comment: @Flimzy: My experience in Asia is that it's quite common to shop duty-free at your destination.  Even in rule-happy Singapore people queue to buy liquor after touchdown.

Comment: I presume the idea of "duty free on arrivial" (which most countries don't allow but some do) is to divert purchases from foreign airports to local ones. Of course it has the side effect that people can buy items that would be impractical to bring with them.